# Include custom sidebar and remove main sidebar in DWQA

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I want to remove main sidebar from dwqa-question page and want to add custom sidebar in that page.

I wrote a code for it in functions.php :

```
    function dwqa_theme_register_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Single Question', 'multinews' ),
    'id'            => 'dqwa',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
     ) );
     }
     add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dwqa_theme_register_sidebar' );

     function remove_main_sidebar_dwqa_question(){
     if ( is_singular('dwqa-question') ){
     unregister_sidebar( 'Main Sidebar' );
     }
     }
     add_action( 'widget_init', 'remove_main_sidebar_dwqa_question' );
```

And this code in page.php :

```
    <?php if ( is_singular('dwqa-question') ): ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('dqwa') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Below is the output screenshot :

[single question page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2DrE.png)

Comment: This is wordpress and plugins specific. Have a try with the wordpress part of stackexchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: ok @Random  but, if you can help me here for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need to de-register the main sidebar every time, it will take time to render the output. Just write the code in **siderbar.php**. Here I am mixing some of your code with.

```
<?php 
        if ( is_singular('dwqa-question') )
        { 
            dynamic_sidebar('dqwa');
        }
        else
        {
          /** FOR OTHER THAN DWQA ***/
          dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar'); //I might be wrong on ID
        }//end if 
 ?>
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanx it works me for unregister main sidebar from this page. one more help please ? @Tristup

Comment: Please tell me that.

Comment: css style of dqwa sidebar is not appearing same as main sidebar as you can see in image, why ? @Tristup

Comment: Can you please give me the url so I can see whether the class is available in widgets or not?

Comment: it is http://competitionmantra.com and  http://competitionmantra.com/en/question/demonetisation/ @Tristup

Comment: Where did you write that code....seems the style is not loading. main.css is css file loading in the page you mentioned

Comment: i wrote a code in functions.php and in page.php as mentioned in question here

Comment: Style code should be written in css files. Can you tell me what style you need here.

Comment: same style as main-sidebar had @Tristup

Comment: I achieved style same as main-sidebar by providing custom css